# How to share a single session between more than one user at the same time on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: session

Is it possible to share the same session for more than one user at the same time?! if yes how to do that?

Comment: what king of session do you mean, xrdp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `sesman.ini` and unders the section **[Sessions]** add the following :

```
AllowSharing=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tmux** and **GNU Screen** are well-known utilities which allow multiplexing of virtual consoles. Using either, it is possible to start a session, detach, move to a different machine and resume the session in uninterrupted progress. It's also possible to use these tools to share a single session between more than one user at the same time. 
[This is a nice tutorial to learn about](http://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen)

Comment: More info from the tutorial would be nice.